# Linux command line emulator that can run scripts, in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, virtual, debian-based

Hey I was just wondering if anyone has made a version of Debian written in Javascript, just for a test. I know it would not be able to do unlimited stuff, but what Javascript lets it have should be enough.

Here is a C64 emulator I have found, but it's too simple? http://www.kingsquare.nl/jsc64

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://jpc.sourceforge.net/demos_linuxdemos.html

This sounds like a truly horrible idea to me. So it should be fun, good luck with it! :)

Comment: writing an x86 emulator in javascript sound like a lot of fun indeed. I think it has already been done in java. not  that x86 is the only processor that debian is running on.